# Xlviewer not able to render excel sheet

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

Team,

I have an unusual problem of XLviewer.aspx not able to render the excel sheet by itself but takes the help of defualt client application to render....meaning it takes the help of installed office excel application 2010 and renders it.

To give you some background, i am trying to export the excel out of datagrid view.I observed that the datagridview export to excel code saves the generated excel file as excel 97-2007 by default. This cannot be opened by xlviewer. However, when i save in the format of "Excel worksheet" , the file gets opened by xlviewer.

Any idea, how do i save the excel in the format of Excel worksheet when i export? or are there any other ideas you can share?